# parsec: is there an easy way to allow comments/whitespace everywhere in the grammar?

Tags: haskell, parsec

How do you deal with whitespace and comments? The fragments that are usually removed during syntactic analysis stage? I want to enable comments everywhere in my document that I am parsing. Is adding these in every elementary parser that I define the only option?

Comment: The most common (library independent) way to do this is to simply have a tokenizing step before the actual parsing, and have that discard all whitespace and comments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way that it is done in `Text.Parsec.Token` is to have every token consume the whitespace and comments which follow it.

This is done through the help of the `lexeme` combinator:

```
lexeme p = do { x <- p; whitespace; return x }
```

which runs a parser `p`, consumes the white space following it and returns whatever `p` returned.

When you look at the source of `makeTokenParser` [(link)](https://github.com/aslatter/parsec/blob/master/Text/Parsec/Token.hs#L346) you'll see that many of the token parsers are wrapped using the `lexeme` combinator, e.g.:

```
symbol name
    = lexeme (string name)
```

Using this approach, the comments for `lexeme` [(link)](https://github.com/aslatter/parsec/blob/master/Text/Parsec/Token.hs#L215) point out that the only time your parser needs to explicitly consume white space is at the beginning of the input to skip over any white space before the first token.

Answer (score 7):

You should use parsec’s abilities to define a “token parser”. The idea is that you define the characteristics of your language in a `LanguageDef`, and then use the derived parsers in the resulting `TokenParser`, e.g. `identifier`, `integer` etc. You can take the `lexeme` function from your `TokenParser` to turn any parser that you might have into one that swallows all trailing whitespace.

See [makeTokenParser](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.9/docs/Text-Parsec-Token.html#v:makeTokenParser) for more details.

An example is [this code](https://bitbucket.org/nomeata/arbtt/src/d20c98bbb54b27e681bee358cc8e9eda34dcf576/src/Categorize.hs?at=master#Categorize.hs-109) that I wrote. It’s real-world-code, so maybe not as educating as a good tutorial, but you can see how I define `lang = makeTokenParser...` and then in the following parsers use parsers like `whiteSpace lang`, `parens lang`. `parseTime` is an example where I use `lexeme` around a “normal” parser.

Comment: Is there any example of how to use the token ?